# Deprecated permissions om Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm setting up an Android projects with biometrics and it turns out that the Biometric permissions have been replaced in API 28.

How should I declare my manifest as, given that we have to use the principle of least privilege.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

or should it be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the new policy in Google Console, you couldn't use this permission on the `Manifest`. So you should `Request` and `Check` in **Activity**.

**API< 28:**

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

**API >= 28:**

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```